What is the legal obligation for councils to "look into all reports" of child protection concerns?
It is on the news that TV presenter Kirsty Allsopp is being investigated by the Royal Borough of Kensington and Chelsea (RBKC) over child protection concerns over her 15 years old son's Interrail trip in Europe.
A spokesperson for RBKC confirmed to the Guardian that an investigation into the allegation was ongoing and they had a legal obligation to look into all reports.
What is this legal obligation?  Is there really no threshold below which complaints are not "looked into"?

If there were a threshold, then making the judgment as to whether a particular complaint was above or below the threshold, would be "looking into" the complaint....

@JamesK If there is a law that says that then that would be the answer.

The council are probably alluding to section 47 of the Children Act 1989:

Where a local authority ... have reasonable cause to suspect that a child who lives, or is found, in their area is suffering ... the authority shall make, or cause to be made, such enquiries as they consider necessary to enable them to decide whether they should take any action to safeguard or promote the child’s welfare

A report that a child was being neglected would probably give "reasonable cause". This doesn't specify exactly what form the investigation should take, only "as necessary" to determine what action to take.
So there is a "threshold" below which no action is taken, the process of determining if a particular report is above or below that threshold is what the council is talking about.

Put simply, the authority can't just dismiss credible reports out of hand, they have to check them out.

Conversely, if someone told the council that you had been renting your child out to a cabal of Satanic Hollywood stars and Democratic Party elected officials so they could achieve eternal youth by harvesting adenochrome from his blood, that could likely ignore you because you have not provided reasonable cause to investigate, and because  they would not "consider necessary" any further investigation.

@bdb484 though you may be detained under section 5 of the mental health act.

@JamesK Let's hope so.
